# Pushing all iterations of a loop into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

Consider this:

```
//finalArray = [];

//rangeArr = [1,2,3,4,5]

//allMultiplesArr = [[1,2,3,4...100],[2,4,6,8...100],[3,6,9,12...100],[4,8,12,16...100],[5,10,15,20...100]]

for(var m=0;m<allMultiplesArr.length;m++)
{
  for(var n =0;n<allMultiplesArr[m].length;n++)
{
    for(var l =0;l<=rangeArr.length;l++)
    {
    if(allMultiplesArr[m][n] % rangeArr[l]  == 0)
    {
    ///finalArray.push(allMultiples[m][n])   
    }
  }
}
}
```

I have a 2D array `finalArray` which holds 5 elements. Each element counts up to 100 by each element of `rangeArr` respectively. Then I loop through the outer array, and through each element in the inner array defined by `allMultiplesArr[m][n]`.

Then I am aiming to make the statement: if the numbers of each inner array (`allMultiplesArr[m][n]`) are evenly divided into **ALL** elements of `rangeArr` (meaning 1,2,3,4,5) **THEN** push `allMultiples[m][n]` into `finalArray`.

What my code currently does, is that it pushes every single number that is evenly divided by ANY of the elements in `rangeArr`, and I want it to **ONLY** push those numbers that are evenly divided by all elements of `rangeArr` into `finalArray` meaning push **ONLY** the numbers that are evenly divided by 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5. Which essentially gives me the common multiples of these numbers, up to the number 100.

Comment: Congratulations?...Is there a question?

Comment: Yes, I right now my finalArray will end up with MANY numbers all of which are evenly divided by 1 OR 2 OR 3 etc.. I want ONLY the ones that are evenly divided by all to be inserted. As in, a multiple of all the numbers in rangeArr, and not just any of them.

Please re read the question. I have tried my best to be clear

Comment: *"I want ONLY the ones that are evenly divided by **all to be inserted**."* What does that even mean? You should make a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, let me break this down for you. Right now, its going to loop through my 2D array. and go through all the numbers in the inner array. If any of those numbers are evenly divided by (1,2,3,4,OR,5) it will be inserted into final array. I want it to be inserted into finalArray ONLY if the number is evenly divided by all as in (1,2,3,4, AND 5.. all of them, not just one of them) for example 60 is an acceptable number. 2 is not.

Comment: @zer00ne hey man, if you refer to the answer below, you will see it is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please suggest to me how I can reword my question in such a manner, as to reach the correct provided answer below? Or perhaps consider the possibility that it was clear enough since I received an exact answer? Thanks.

Comment: @mattHurting, no need to make it any clearer, your last comment was much more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript every function to check weather all elements match the condition.

```js
for(var m=0;m<allMultiplesArr.length;m++) {
  
  for(var n =0;n<allMultiplesArr[m].length;n++) {
    
    var valid = rangeArr.every(function(range){
      return (allMultiplesArr[m][n] % range  == 0) 
    });
    
    if(valid) {
      finalArray.push(allMultiplesArr[m][n])   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man !! This is exactly what I've been looking for.